# How companies send texts/calls with an ID?

Tags: mobile

I got a text today from a company that's definitely not in my contacts but the text appeared with their name at the top as if they were. This occasionally happens with calls too.

An example of this in the news is here: http://www.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/whats-on/whats-on-news/parklife-mum-text-revellers-after-7116577

How do companies do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the companies are doing anything special, but rather your phone is smart enough to associate the number with the public information available about them.

On my Android phone, in the Phone app Settings there is an option Caller ID by Google, that can be turn on or off, to show names of people and businesses not in your contacts.